# A loop to extract URLS from several text files

Tags: python, for-loop, extract

I am attempting to extract a list of URLS from several files using a for loop, however this is resulting in a list of URLS from only the first file, repeated 10 times. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Also, I am an absolute beginner at this, so I will presume that there are much better ways of trying to achieve what I want, however this is what I have so far.

```
type_urls = []
y = 0

for files in cwk_dir:
    while y < 10:
        open('./cwkfiles/cwkfile{}.crawler.idx'.format(y))
        lines = r.text.splitlines()
        header_loc = 7
        name_loc = lines[header_loc].find('Company Name')
        type_loc = lines[header_loc].find('Form Type')
        cik_loc = lines[header_loc].find('CIK')
        filedate_loc = lines[header_loc].find('Date Filed')
        url_loc = lines[header_loc].find('URL')
        firstdata_loc = 9
        for line in lines[firstdata_loc:]:
            company_name = line[:type_loc].strip()
            form_type = line[type_loc:cik_loc].strip()
            cik = line[cik_loc:filedate_loc].strip()
            file_date = line[filedate_loc:url_loc].strip()
            page_url = line[url_loc:].strip()
            typeandurl = (form_type, page_url)
            type_urls.append(typeandurl)
        y = y + 1
```

Comment: You can replace `y = 0`, `y = y + 1`, and `while y < 10:` logic with just a `for y in range(10):` on the place where you have the `while`. And it would be better if you could post a sample of your `.idx` file contents, `cwk_dir` value/type etc. In other words, a complete reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The .idx files are contained within the cwk_dir, a folder within Anaconda notebook, and the .idx files themselves are SEC Edgar files. I am trying to extract 10-K filings URLs. I have managed to do this for one URL but am struggling with this loop to try and run through the entire list. I have 75 .idx files but was attempting 10 to start with so that I'm not waiting too long to know my code doesn't work

Comment: So, if I got it right, you want to go through `cwk_dir/cwkfile*.idx` list and process one by one, is that right?

Comment: yes that's right, and I would like each process to result in form_type and page_url being added to the type_urls list

Comment: Check my answer for a starting point using Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more Pythonic way using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and Python 3:

```py
from pathlib import Path

cwk_dir = Path('./cwkfiles')

type_urls = []
header_loc = 7
firstdata_loc = 9

for cwkfile in cwk_dir.glob('cwkfile*.crawler.idx'):
    with cwkfile.open() as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        name_loc = lines[header_loc].find('Company Name')
        type_loc = lines[header_loc].find('Form Type')
        cik_loc = lines[header_loc].find('CIK')
        filedate_loc = lines[header_loc].find('Date Filed')
        url_loc = lines[header_loc].find('URL')
        for line in lines[firstdata_loc:]:
            company_name = line[:type_loc].strip()
            form_type = line[type_loc:cik_loc].strip()
            cik = line[cik_loc:filedate_loc].strip()
            file_date = line[filedate_loc:url_loc].strip()
            page_url = line[url_loc:].strip()
            type_urls.append((form_type, page_url))
```

If you want to test on a small batch of files, replace `cwk_dir.glob('cwkfile*.crawler.idx')` with `cwk_dir.glob('cwkfile[0-9].crawler.idx')`. That will give you the first then files if they are sequentially numbered, starting from 0.

And here is better way to put it all together and in a more readable way:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def get_offsets(header):
    return dict(
        company_name = header.find('Company Name'),
        form_type = header.find('Form Type'),
        cik = header.find('CIK'),
        file_date = header.find('Date Filed'),
        page_url = header.find('URL')
    )


def get_data(line, offsets):
    return dict(
        company_name = line[:offsets['form_type']].strip(),
        form_type = line[offsets['form_type']:offsets['cik']].strip(),
        cik = line[offsets['cik']:offsets['file_date']].strip(),
        file_date = line[offsets['file_date']:offsets['page_url']].strip(),
        page_url = line[offsets['page_url']:].strip()
    )


cwk_dir = Path('./cwkfiles')
types_and_urls = []
header_line = 7
first_data_line = 9

for cwkfile in cwk_dir.glob('cwkfile*.crawler.idx'):
    with cwkfile.open() as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        offsets = get_offsets(lines[header_line])
        for line in lines[first_data_line:]:
            data = get_data(line, offsets)
            types_and_urls.append((data['form_type'], data['page_url']))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, however I am still running into problems. If I try running the first program with [0-9] I end up still only saving the data from the first file. If I run it with the * I get a UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'.

Comment: The if I run the second program I get a SyntaxError: Invalid syntax in line 7. I have attempted to traceback to see if I can find the error, but I am not familiar enough with those arguments to find it.

Comment: Ok, I think I've fixed it. Using the first program line 7 now reads ` with cwkfile.open(encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f: `

Comment: @Cornflour, so did it work? Which one did you use? Are you still getting any errors?

Comment: @Cornflour, fixed the syntax error on the second version. I missed commas separating dictionaries items.

Comment: Thank you, yes it did work, I used the first program, replacing line 7 with `with cwkfile.open(encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f: `This gave me what I needed with no further errors

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the second file, the while condition fails as `y` is already 10.
Try setting `y` back to 0 just before the while loop:

```py
for files in cwk_dir:
    y = 0
    while y < 10:
        ...
```

And as you're opening the file in the first line inside the while loop, you probably need to close it when exiting the loop.

Comment: As above, I have removed those arguments and changed to ```for y in range(10):``` and I have also added ```close()``` to the end, however I am still having what appears to be the same issue